# Comparing two array for

Tags: php

I have two arrays like this:

```
$arr1 = array('/^under.*/','/^develop.*/','/^repons*/');
$arr2 = array('understand','underconstruction','developer','develope','hide','here','some')
```

I want to match the two arrays and return an array of words starting with the patterns in `$arr1`.

How do I do this in php?

Comment: Must `$arr1` be an array? You can combine those patterns into one `/^(under|develop|repons).*/` but perhaps you have other more complex patterns. Actually, no regex is needed because they're all just the start of the string. `strpos()` would be fine.

Comment: Create a regexp and use `preg_grep` for example

Comment: array_filter() using fnmatch() to check the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $arr1 = array('/^under.*/','/^develop.*/','/^repons*/');
    $arr2 = array('understand','underconstruction','developer','develope','hide','here','some');
    $result = array();

    foreach($arr1 as $pattern) {

        foreach($arr2 as $value) {

            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $value, $matches))
                $result[] = $matches[0][0];
        }

    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => understand [1] => underconstruction [2] => developer [3] => develope )
```